# How can I make SQL throw an error when the VARCHAR variable is too small for the assigned value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the script:

```
DECLARE @Login VARCHAR(10)

SET @Login = N'sysprogress'

PRINT @Login
```

At this point @Login has sysprogres (1 character missing at the end).

Is there a SQL option that will cause an error to be thrown when this happens rather than silently truncating the data?

Comment: There are options for inserting or updating long values.  I don't think there are options for assignment.

Comment: There is no option. There is a [closely related Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/622699/stored-procedures-should-throw-error-message-when-called-with-string-values-which-exceed-lenght-of-stored-procedure-parameter) open, although it specifically relates to truncation within a parameter rather than a variable, the same principal applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of no server-level option that can be set to avoid this.   It can be handled programmatically.

You can check the length of the string with LEN() and if it is longer than you want, you can raise an error with RAISERROR().

[Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2857/silent-truncation-of-sql-server-data-inserts/) is some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a test variable and check it and then set your variable or raise an error.

```
DECLARE @Login VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(max)

SET @Test = N'sysprogress'

IF LEN(@Test) > 10 
BEGIN RAISERROR('Longer than 10',16,1) END
ELSE set @Login =  @Test

select @Login
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define Length appropriately,there is no option to check if value is more than length..

One lengthy way is to declare table and copy from that ,if you are not sure of length ..

```
declare   @table table
(
loginn varchar(10)
)

insert into @table
select 'sysprogress'--this fails
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 7
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

- For **inserting** or **updating** use `constraint` or define the `Length` you want.
- For **assigenment** use `Len()`.